# How access second div with same id using querySelectorAll javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here, I have two div on my webpage both div have almost same data.
accept type attribute.

My first div attribute have type="timeline".
and Second div attribute type ="slideshow".

When my page load it only detects the first div.

But I have a condition if my div type equal to slideshow then my code run but it detects only first div.

Here is my code.

```html
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
  <section>
    <header>Title One</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Two</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Three</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Four</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

```js
var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
var myNodeList = divSlide.length;
for(i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
  var divMain = document.getElementById("slide");
  console.log(divMain);

  var align = divMain.getAttribute("type");
  console.log(align);
  console.log(myNodeList)

  if(align=='slideshow'){
    console.log("my working code");
  }
}
```

What should i do.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: ID are supposed to be unique in dom. Try replacing id with class instead

Comment: In HTML, ID of an element should *always be unique*. So _querySelectorAll_ will always return you the first element only as it assumes there are none others. If you want to group your elements, use _class_ instead of _id_.

Comment: how can i access it my type base if my type is desirable then condition execute.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few of mistakes in your code that we need to fix first.

**First,** you shouldn't use the same id value more than once in your code so you need to replace the id with a class (even though our code can still work with id here).

**Second mistake** - in your for loop you are using the wrong variable "myNodeList.length", myNodeList variable already is the length so it does not have a length property. you should instead use the divSlide variable like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < divSlide.length; i++)
```

**Third mistake-** in order to access the current item that is being looped over you should use the variable that holds the list (which is *divSlide* here)and then add to it **i** in brackets to indicate the current index in use, like this

```
  var divMain = divSlide[i];

  // instead of this: var divMain = document.getElementById("slide");
```

**Fourth** - you should in most cases use triple = signs to check for values. so instead of == you should use ===

**this is how the code will look like finally:**

```
 var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
 var myNodeList = divSlide.length;

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", functionName)

 function functionName(){

    for(i = 0; i < divSlide.length; i++) {
    var divMain = divSlide[i];

    var align = divMain.getAttribute("type");

    if(align ==='slideshow'){
      console.log("my working code");
    }
 } 

}
```

[and this is codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdpGqz)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `div` by `type` attribute like this:

**HTML**

```
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
  this is timeline
</div>
<div type='slideshow' id='slide'>
  this is slideshow
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#slide[type=slideshow]') // get div that has id='slide' and type='slideshow'
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/8r7o3ws4/7/)